# multivalued field sorting on SOLR 7.2.1

Tags: solr

i use a server with solr 7.3.0 for testing. my scheme has some multivalued string fields like

```
<field name="rating" type="string" omitNorms="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

On solr 7.3.0 a url query for sorting for the field "rating" works fine. Something like this:

server-name1:8983/sorl/core/search?q=*&sort=rating DESC

But recently i use a slave and the above mentioned solr 7.3.0 server is the master server.
The slave has a lesser version (7.2.1) installed. Because the server exists longer and this was was the latest version back then. I never bothered to update this yet.
But now the same query as above

server-name2:8983/sorl/core/search?q=*&sort=rating DESC

returns a error message:

"msg":"can not sort on multivalued field:rating"

My question is: is this just a recently implemented feature or did i miss something? I could update to 7.3.0 for the slave as well, but it just want to be sure if this is just a version issue.

Comment: of course i tried 7.2.1 and 7.3.0 documentary, but i am not exactly sure what exactly i have to look for. google results indicate that this was not a feature for a long period of time. the last recorded version i found  where you have to do a workaround was 6.6. and of course 7.3.0 was my first version i had to play around, so i was quite suprised when it didn't work on 7.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this was implemented for 7.3.0. See [SOLR-11854 - multiValued PrimitiveFieldType should implicitly sort on min/max based on the asc/desc keyword](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11854).

To find out if something has changed between versions, refer to the changelog for [the new version](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_3_0/changes/Changes.html). This is listed under the "New features" section:

> SOLR-11854: multivalued primitive fields can now be sorted by implicitly choosing the min/max value for asc/desc sort orders. (hossman)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm still a little bit "fresh" so sorry for not enough research effort.

Comment: No worries! It's a neat thing when you come across something like this, and there's a well maintained changelog included with every release. Not many people know about the changelog, and the documentation doesn't keep track of when something was added to Solr.